# How to test a function for condition and stabilty?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, condition-number

How can I test the condition and stability of the following function, for values $x=0$, $x=0.25$ and $x=10^{-5}$? 
$$
f(x) = \frac{1-cos(2x)}x 
$$
What should one do here? For condition, I think I should do the following: 
$$
K = \left|\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \cdot x\right|
$$
 and check if it's $>> 1$ or $< 10$.

1) Am I right for the condition? And how to check for that $x$ values given above? If not, how would be the right way?

2) How to check the stability also for that values?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You could say $\cos 2x = 1-2\sin^2 x$ and then $f(x) =  \frac {2\sin^2 x}{x}$ and you might have some experience already with the function $\frac {\sin x}{x}$

Comment: because of the undefined form 0/0 you mean?

Comment: Your function is undefined at $0.$  However, the limit exists.

Comment: yep, but how to answer the questions above? What should I do in the exam for this problem?

Comment: would be greateful for any help! I have my last exam tomorrow, and this comes every time :/